# is it possible to draw on richtextbox (WPF, C#)

Tags: c#, wpf, drawing, richtextbox

I programmed a text editor. The file can be saved in text or RTF format.

```xml
<RichTextBox Grid.Row="2" 
             x:Name="richtxtbox" 
             BorderBrush="#FFF1EDED"
             Block.LineHeight="2"                     
             Padding="2 5"
             SpellCheck.IsEnabled="True" 
             ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
             SelectionChanged="txtEditor_SelectionChanged" >
</RichTextBox>
```

[image: Texteditor created with C#, WPF, Richtextbox control]

Now I want to draw different shapes like lines, triangles, circles, etc. on `RichTextBox`.

Like Draw in Microsoft Word:

[image: Microsoft Word]

Comment: The `RichTextBox` control does not support the picture drawing functions automatically.  The Rich Text Format (RTF) Specification has the **Pictures** chapter that describes the picture related _control words_. You can see descriptions of the pictures _control words_  in the following document:  [Rich Text Format (RTF) Version 1.5 Specification](http://www.biblioscape.com/rtf15_spec.htm#Heading11). But the implementation on your own.

Comment: You can add any kind of UIElement to t he document of the RichTextBox. This means you can add a Canvas to place Shape objects.

Comment: [FlowDocument.Blocks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.documents.flowdocument.blocks?view=windowsdesktop-6.0#remarks)

Comment: [Examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.documents.blockuicontainer?view=windowsdesktop-6.0#examples)